# How to use transients and variables

Tags: transient

I am trying to implement transient fragments, I've been doing what is suggested here: http://css-tricks.com/wordpress-fragment-caching-revisited/

While it is working for headers, footers, landing pages, I am having issues making it work for those sections that include variables.

This is my code in functions.php:

```
function fragment_cache($key, $ttl, $function) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    call_user_func($function);
    return;
  }
  $key = apply_filters('fragment_cache_prefix', 'fragment_cache_').$key;
  $output = get_transient($key);
  if ( empty($output) ) {
    ob_start();
    call_user_func($function);
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    set_transient($key, $output, $ttl);
  }
  echo $output;
}
```

And here is a simplified version  of my code on a single page (I'm using Advanced Custom Fieds repeaters, but it's no concern to this issue I think):

```
while ( have_rows('images') ): the_row();
  fragment_cache('cms_images_text' . $post->ID, WEEK_IN_SECONDS, function() {
    $gallery_image = get_sub_field('image');
    $gallery_image_small = $gallery_image['sizes']['square-small'];
    echo '<img src="' . $gallery_image_small .  '">;
  });
endwhile;
```

My issue is that within this while loop, I get returned four identical images. How can I get this solved?

Comment: Where does `$gallery_image` come from? Also: Please do not delete and repost questions. This will get you banned. Thank you.

Comment: It comes from an Advanced Custom Field, I didn't add the whole code here

Comment: Can you confirm that you have read and understood the second part of my last comment? Also: Can you confirm that ACF isn't the problem?

Comment: I deleted the original question because I thought I got it fixed, but then I am stuck again and decided to copy-paste some parts of it - won't happen again

Comment: Yes ACF is not the problem, i think the cause is that the variable name stays the same and its content gets cached somehow.

Comment: Please file an [edit] and show us how the cache connects to your snippet. It's very unclear and not reproducible.

Comment: Added the get_sub_field that maybe was puzzling you

Comment: @Akmur the function `fragment_cache()` is defined, but never used in the code we can see... to help you we need to know where and how you are using it.

Comment: Sorry you're right, I added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saving the data in a loop under the same key for each iteration. You'll have to add the index of the current iteration of the loop to the key if you want a unique value for each. Something like:

```
$i = 0;
while ( have_rows('images') ): the_row();
  fragment_cache('cms_images_text_' . $i . '_' . $post->ID, WEEK_IN_SECONDS, function() {
    $gallery_image = get_sub_field('image');
    $gallery_image_small = $gallery_image['sizes']['square-small'];
    echo '<img src="' . $gallery_image_small .  '">';
  });
  $i++;
endwhile;
```

Or perhaps just save the entire loop's contents under a single key.